# How to direct a user from a page in a Django app to a static web page found on the same server

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

Assume that I have my Django app running at '/var/project/my_django_project/' and I want to direct the user to '/var/project/static_website/index.html' when a button is clicked in a template located at '/var/project/my_django_project/templates/my_template.html'. How can I achieve this?

Edit: I am using apache2 web server

Comment: are you using a web server like Nginx or Apache? you can add this location to your web server and when you click on that link instead of django handling the request your web server returns the static page.

Comment: I am using apache2. By "you can add this location to the web server" what do you exactly mean?

Comment: Please provide us with your current related view (views.py extract) and urls (urls.py). It looks like your looking for [`return redirect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut

Comment: The thing is, the HTML file I am trying to direct to is not defined in the views.py or urls.py because the static website is not part of my Django app, it is just on the same server as the Django app. Also, that static website is huge in size (>50GB) so I don't really want to directly integrate it into the Django app.